# What is the purpose of condition variables in Monitors?

Tags: c, operating-system

What is the purpose of condition variables in Monitors? Why really do we need the condition variables? It may sound something stupid to ask, but never mind I am really new at this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Im voting to close this question because: _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **condition variable** is basically a **container of threads** that are waiting for a certain condition. Monitors provide a mechanism for threads to temporarily give up exclusive access in order to wait for some condition to be met, before regaining exclusive access and resuming their task.Reference link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)).

Conceptually a condition variable is a queue of threads, associated with a monitor, on which a thread may wait for some condition to become true.